# Cakephp Sql Query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

How can I write these kind of statements in a cakephp sql query way.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `officers` 
WHERE ((slot1_min<=00 AND slot1_max>=0) OR (slot2_min<=850 AND slot2_max>=850))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TRY:**

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array(
       'OR' => array(
          array(
              'AND' => array(
                  array('slot1_min <=' => 0),
                  array('slot1_max >=' => 0),
              )
          ),
          array(
              'AND' => array(
                  array('slot2_min <=' => 850),
                  array('slot2_max >=' => 850),
              )
          ),  
       )
    )
);
$officers = $this->Officer->find('all',$options);
```